# Widgets not visible or not filling all intended space

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display 2 frames and one canvas such that:

- The red frame must be on top of the window and spans over the canvas and the blue frame.
- The blue frame and the canvas are on the bottom of the window. The canvas is on the right.

I am not getting the expected results. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
class Mine(Frame):
   def __init__(self,master):
       Frame.__init__(self,master)
       self.frameh()
       self.framev()
       self.thecanvas()
   # horizontal frame on top spanning over 2 columns
   def frameh(self):
       self.fh=Frame(root,width=400,height=40,bg="red")
       self.fh.grid(sticky=N,row=0,columnspan=2)
   # vertical frame on bottom
   def framev(self):
       self.fv=Frame(root,height=200,bg="blue")
       self.fv.grid(sticky=S+W,row=1,column=0)
   def thecanvas(self):
       self.c=Canvas(root,width=500,height=200,bg="black")
       self.c.grid(sticky=S+E,row=1,column=1)

if __name__=="__main__":
   root=Tk()       
   root.wm_title("mine")
   m=Mine(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are the expected results, and what do you get instead? We can't run this without an appropriate image - is that necessary to replicate the issue?

Comment: the expected results are those highlighted using the black small balls. The image is just an icon, i will remove it from my question

Comment: @Nakkini I have edited your title (more precise) and your tags (removing the ones that have no the meaning you intended) (cf. my others comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to set `columnspan=2` for `frameh`, so that it spans both the `framev` and `thecanvas` columns (plus extra `sticky` to make it fill the full width), and define a non-zero minimum width for `framev`:

```
...
def frameh(self):
    self.fh=Frame(root, width=400, height=40, bg="red")
    self.fh.grid(sticky=N+E+W, row=0, columnspan=2)

def framev(self):
    self.fv=Frame(root, height=200, width=100, bg="blue")
    self.fv.grid(sticky=S+W, row=1, column=0)
...
```

This gives me:

[image: Mondrian-esque Tkinter window]

Comment: thank you, I did what you asked me to do, but i see only the red frame and the canvas

Comment: Have you set a non-zero width for `framev`? I have added what I see.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I forgot the width on the bottomw frame. it works just fine. Thank you very much

Comment: You should also edit your question's title to be more informative and remove the tags except python and tkinter (tags are not keywords, each tag has a precise meaning which you can see by hovering your mouse on it)

Comment: @EricLevieil that would be better as a comment on the *question* than on an *answer*. Alternatively, propose an edit yourself!

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right. The first version of my comment also mentions accepting the answer. I can edit the question, but isn't it better to explain to new members how to improve rather than editing their posts?

Comment: @EricLevieil you can do both! Suggest an edit, then add a comment explaining why (with a link to the Help Center, where relevant). If SE didn't want users to make edits, they wouldn't bribe us with +2 rep.

Comment: @jonrsharpe edit done, I am waiting for peer-reviewing before commenting.